# .NET MVC unobtrusive validation / checkbox captcha

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate, captcha, unobtrusive-validation

I'm trying to implement a checkbox captcha I read about here:
http://uxmovement.com/forms/captchas-vs-spambots-why-the-checkbox-captcha-wins/

However I'm having issues adding the checkbox with client side javascript and unobtrusive validation.

I implemented a checkbox with unobtrusive validation based on Darin Dimitrov's answer here: [MVC unobtrusive validation on checkbox not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923430/mvc-unobtrusive-validation-on-checkbox-not-working) which works perfectly.

However, once I remove the checkbox from my view and add it with this jquery code instead:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function (jQuery) {
    $('div.test').append($("<input>").attr("id", "AcceptsTerms")
                                     .attr("type", "checkbox")
                                     .val("true")
                                     .attr("name", "AcceptsTerms")
                                     .attr("data-val-required", "This field is required.")
                                     .attr("data-val-mustbetrue", "You must accept the terms and conditions")
                                     .attr("data-val", "true")
                                     .addClass("input-validation-error"));

    $('div.test').append($('<input>').attr("type", "hidden")
                                     .val("value", "false")
                                     .attr("name", "AcceptsTerms"));

    $('div.test').append($("<label>").attr("for", "AcceptsTerms")
                                     .html("Accept terms and conditions"));

    $('div.test').append($('<span>').addClass("field-validation-error")
                                    .attr("data-valmsg-replace", "true")
                                    .attr("data-valmsg-for", "AcceptsTerms"));
});
```

it no longer wants to validate. Are there any known issues with adding form elements after the document has loaded and unobtrusive validation? If so, has any attempted to implement this or have any suggestions on how to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I found the solution.

As I suspected and as Sparky mentioned: *the jQuery Validate plugin is initialized once on the DOM ready event*. Due to this, all I had to do after adding my input dynamically was to reinitialize unobtrusive validation.

I added this first for the rule:

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool("mustbetrue", "required");
```

Then I added this to reinitialize unobtrusive validation:

```
$("form").removeData('validator');
$("form").removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($("form"));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Quote OP:**

> However, once I remove the checkbox from my view and add it with this
>   jquery code instead: {snip} it no longer wants to validate. Are there
>   any known issues with adding form elements after the document has
>   loaded and unobtrusive validation? If so, has any attempted to
>   implement this or have any suggestions on how to go about this?

This happens because the jQuery Validate plugin is *initialized* once on the DOM ready event but your checkbox does not yet exist.  It's an all-too-common misconception that `.validate()` is called repeatedly as the user interacts with the form.  It is not.  `.validate()` is called **once** on DOM ready to *initialize* the plugin and form validation happens automatically when triggered by the default events.

If you need to dynamically alter the form's HTML, you must use one of the [plugin's built-in methods](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation#Plugin_methods) to dynamically alter its options.

In your case, you need to use the [`rules('add')` method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules), sometime *after* your jQuery adds the checkbox, to alter the `rules` option to apply your checkbox rule(s).

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('div.test').append($("<input>").attr("id", "AcceptsTerms"). ... );

    $('#AcceptsTerms').rules('add', {
        required: true,
        another_rule: parameter,
        messages: { // <- this item is optional
            required: "custom message"
            another_rule: "custom message for this rule"
        }
    });

    ...

});
```

Comment: Sparky thanks for the reply. I attempted the code and it didn't work. I don't believe this isn't working because I'm working with jquery unobtrusive validation and not just jquery validation. Did you take this into account with your answer?

Comment: @GregB, Microsoft's `unobtrusive` validation plugin depends upon the jQuery Validate plugin. The method outlined in my answer is just the standard way to dynamically alter the rules with jQuery Validate. Since you're making these kinds of customizations, there's less of a point in using `unobtrusive` and you may want to just use jQuery Validate alone.  I've seen many ASP developers go that route in favor of more control.