# Asp.Net MVC and custom unobtrusive validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I'm trying to get a custom rule "mustbetrue" working. Based loosely on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923430/mvc-unobtrusive-validation-on-checkbox-not-working):
My issue is that when I submit the form the client side validation doesn't give me an error (doesn't make the validation text appear).
In addition I've put a break point in the jscript validation method and it never gets fired. The wireup code that adds the adapter *does* get fired. No errors in the console.

What am I doing wrong?

This is what I have server-side:

```
public class MustBeTrueAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value == null) return false;
        try
        {
            return Convert.ToBoolean(value);
        }
        catch (InvalidCastException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata,
                                                                           ControllerContext context)
    {
        yield return new ModelClientValidationRule
            {
                ErrorMessage = this.ErrorMessage,
                ValidationType = "mustbetrue"
            };
    }
}
```

and

```
public class MustBeTrueAttributeAdapter : DataAnnotationsModelValidator<MustBeTrueAttribute>
{
    public MustBeTrueAttributeAdapter(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context, MustBeTrueAttribute attribute)
        : base(metadata, context, attribute)
    {
    }

    public override IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules()
    {
        return new[] { new ModelClientValidationMustBeTrueRule(ErrorMessage) };
    }
}

public class ModelClientValidationMustBeTrueRule : ModelClientValidationRule
{
    public ModelClientValidationMustBeTrueRule(string errorMessage)
    {
        ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
        ValidationType = "mustbetrue";
    }
}
```

and in the global.asax

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        // stuff
        DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(MustBeTrueAttribute), typeof(MustBeTrueAttributeAdapter));
        // stuff
    }
```

and on the object:

```
[MustBeTrue(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Register_TermsNotAccepted", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Global))]
public bool AcceptedTerms { get; set; }
```

client side:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("mustbetrue", function (value, element) {
        if (!this.depend(param, element))
            return "dependency-mismatch";
        return element.checked;
    });
    jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool("mustbetrue", "mustbetrue");
});
```

and the relevant HTML that is output:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-mustbetrue="You must accept the terms and conditions" data-val-required="The AcceptedTerms field is required." id="AcceptedTerms" name="AcceptedTerms" type="checkbox" value="true" class="valid">
```

Comment: Not to stray from the overall goal, but isn't `Required` enough on a checkbox? Unchecked checkboxes aren't sent across the wire, are they (therefore enforcing `Required`)?

Comment: Yes I've heard people state that it works without having to add a new rule. However in practice I've never got it working. Even with the added combination of min max either at 1 or 4.

Comment: @Brad Since a non-null boolean would always have a value, either False or True, then it will always satisfy the Required attribute.  What is needed here is not a Required attribute, but validation that ensures it matches a certain value.  Required just checks whether or not a value is present, but doesn't care whether that value is 0, 1, true, false, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you've already checked that client validation is enabled (either in configuration or in code) then I guess it is because you're adding your adapter **after** unobtrusive validation scripts parses html  [see my answer here for details and possible options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24840976/2164198)