# Data annotation is not working with checkbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

Custom Attribute

```
public class BooleanMustBeTrueAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object propertyValue)
    {
         return propertyValue != null
             && propertyValue is bool
             && (bool)propertyValue;
     }
}
```

Model

```
[MetadataType(typeof(ProductMeta))]
public partial class Product
{
   public virtual bool ItemOwner { get; set; }
}

public class ProductMeta
{
[Required]
[BooleanMustBeTrue(ErrorMessage = "Please tick")]
public virtual bool ItemOwner { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.ItemOwner)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.ItemOwner)
```

Everything above in my code is looking correct but still checkbox validation is not working. 
Above validation is not even applying to the control.

My application is in MVC4.

Please advise.

Comment: @Rico: Unfortunately  No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code

```
public class EnforceTrueAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value == null) return false;
        if (value.GetType() != typeof(bool)) throw new InvalidOperationException("can only be used on boolean properties.");
        return (bool)value == true;
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return "The " + name + " field must be checked in order to continue.";
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        yield return new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ErrorMessage = String.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage) ? FormatErrorMessage(metadata.DisplayName) : ErrorMessage,
            ValidationType = "enforcetrue"
        };
    }
}
```

then add below code to your javascript file.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("enforcetrue", function (value, element, param) {
    return element.checked;
});
jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool("enforcetrue");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get some ideas from this answer: [How to handle Booleans/CheckBoxes ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245185/how-to-handle-booleans-checkboxes-in-asp-net-mvc-2-with-dataannotations?rq=1). Especially from answer with 43 up-votes.

Quite possibly your solution lies here: logic: [Required checkbox to be checked using CheckBoxFor](http://goo.gl/ongqC)
with code sample: [MVC Model require true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730183/mvc-model-require-true), which is not much different from the first answer. If worked for other folks, must work for you as well.

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
   public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            if (value == null) return false;
            if (value.GetType() != typeof(bool)) throw new InvalidOperationException("can only be used on boolean properties.");

            return (bool) value == true;
        }
```

Comment: Validation is not even applying to the control.

Comment: pls declare 
[BooleanMustBeTrueAttribute]
instead of this
[BooleanMustBeTrue(ErrorMessage = "Please tick")]
public virtual bool ItemOwner { get; set; }